# python write mp3 AudioSegment slice to file as mp3 without export method

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyaudio, pydub, audiosegment

I have an mp3 live radio stream, which i write locally to an mp3 file using ffmpeg and subprocess Popen (the ffmpeg).

After i open this file with pydub and i wrote the raw_data to pyaudio for hearing the stream.

Now after all, i want to record some parts of the mp3 to an extra mp3 file.

Is it possible to write on demand, the pydub.AudioSegments to an extra file?

I try:

```py
self.record_file.write(slice.raw_data)
```

where slice is the pydub.AudioSegment (which previously i wrote to pyaudio stream) and self.record_file is the record file which i created. I used "wb", but windows media player can't open this file.

if i try:

```
self.record_file.write(chunk)
```

where chunk is bytes i read from the ffmpeg download file, then i can hear but there is a repeat many times after the chunk end.